# Reduce the length of callout line in Pie chart Sencha touch

Tags: charts, sencha-touch-2, pie-chart

Below is the code for a pie chart i have in my Sencha touch app. The issue i face is that whenever the space to display chart is not enough for all labels there are callout lines and labels, but then i want these callout lines to be shorter in length then they are right now because they do not fit my screen and labels get cut.

I cannot find the correct config property for that.

**EDIT** -  **the two charts in image have the same code and are placed in hbox layout in container**

[image]

```
{
         xtype: 'polar',
         itemId: 'pieChart',
         background: 'white',
         store: 'GraphsStore',
         shadow: true,
         innerPadding: 25,
         //bind the chart to a store with the following structure
         //interactions: ['rotate'],

         colors: ["#115fa6", "#94ae0a", "#a61120", "#ff8809", "#ffd13e", "#a61187", "#24ad9a", "#7c7474", "#a66111"],

         //configure the legend.
         legend: {
            position: 'top',
            //width: 100
            hidden: true
         },

         //describe the actual pie series.
         series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            xField: 'g1',
            renderer: function(sprite, config, rendererData, index) {
               var changes = {},
                  store = rendererData.store,
                  curentRecord = store.getData().items[index];
               var text = curentRecord.data.g1;
               changes.text = text;
               return changes;
            },

            label: {
               field: 'name',
               display: 'rotate',
               font: '8px'
            },

            donut: 25,

            style: {
               miterLimit: 5,
               lineCap: 'miter',
               lineWidth: 1
            }
         }]
      }
```

Any pointers will be helpful !
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the chart/series/sprite/PieSlice.js, modify the following two lines:

```
x = centerX + Math.cos(midAngle) * (endRho + 40);
y = centerY + Math.sin(midAngle) * (endRho + 40);
```

Change the 40 to a smaller number.